# Navigation View pane cut off

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I have this issue when opening app, I need Navigation View to open it's pane so, but the problem is that it kinda cut off, until I reopen it with Hamburger Menu Button, why is that, I've tried to reset properties such as IsPaneOpen, etc., but it doesn't help.

This is how it's setup in XAML:

```xml
<Custom:NavigationView x:Name="navigationView" SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1"
                           BackRequested="NavigationView_BackRequested" IsBackEnabled="False" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" PaneDisplayMode="Auto">
```

[image: cut off home and settings menu item icon]

This is how I want it to look like

[image: desired behaviour]

Page code:

```xml
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="appTitlebar">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Window Title" Margin="28 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>

        <Custom:NavigationView x:Name="navigationView" SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1"
                           BackRequested="NavigationView_BackRequested" IsBackEnabled="False" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" PaneDisplayMode="Auto">
            <Custom:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <Custom:NavigationViewItem IsSelected="True" x:Uid="Main_NavMenu_Item_Home" x:Name="menuHome" Icon="Home"/>
            </Custom:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <Frame x:Name="frameRoot"/>
        </Custom:NavigationView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you share the complete navigationview xaml code that could reproduce this problem?

Comment: Sorry for long answer, here is a code for MainPage in edited message

Comment: I tried your code, it looks [well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhtgL.png)in my side.

Comment: So, I figured when issue occurs. If you launch app in windowed mode and pane closed, when you resize window an make pane automatically expand, it works fine, but when you relaunch app with already expanded pane, it will cut off.

Here in video shown how it behaves when app relaunched: https://youtu.be/7kUb5vMEyBY

Comment: Can you set the default panel status as close? And it looks navigationview issue, we suggest you post this problem within Winui Github issue.

Comment: I set PaneDisplayMode to "Left" and it opens fine, but when I resize window and make it small, it wont close and remains expanded. When I use LeftCompact, I see clipping issues but not when app is running, so only in designer. But I want it to automatically change mode depending on window size. When IsPaneOpen set to False, it works as intended but pane is closed, with IsPaneOpen True, it causes this issue, so I guess when IsPaneOpen is not defined, somewhere under the hood is defaults to True, which causes this issue.

Comment: Now the question, how can I make it automatically expand when window is too wide without events and triggers?

Comment: You could use  [`AdaptiveTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger?view=winrt-22621)to detect current window size and process your logic with Setter markup.

Comment: You are welcome, if the comment is helpful, may i convert it as answer for this thread ?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I think it's still better than using IsPaneOpen and PaneDisplayMode directly to change it, I've decided to leave the pane closed in my app and never touch it again, but used AdaptiveTrigger to dynamically change the search bar on the top of my window. But still, clipping issue is still hiding somewhere in the code, even if it looks like it is fixed in my app.